# Loading online videos even with flash / pepper [Ubuntu 16]

Tags: 16.04, crash, video-streaming, pepperflash

I've tried to install flash player which used to work few weeks back, unfortunately not anymore. Another step was pepperflash which works on Facebook but it crashes on web-cams, online movies etc.
Screenshot of crash

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Adobe's flash player [download page](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/). Downloads are now available for Firefox and Chrome (although Chrome should have this built in) for the most recent versions of the Adobe flash player.

Here's a screenshot of the download page for Firefox
[image: ff.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

As of ver 59, Chrome no longer includes pepperflash (they have gone to HTML5)

you can get ver58 here. I think it still has pepperflash
https://www.itechtics.com/download-google-chrome-58-offline-installers-operating-systems/

after installing (or unpacking) locate libpepflashplayer.so and copy it to one for the listed locations

more available here: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php
EDIT:  DO NOT try to reinstall freshplayer, many distros have removed it from their repositories. because google does not support downloading old versions, thus pepper is unavailable from chrome. However, it is pretty easy to find independant archive that have older versions.